# MVC3 install is not working on at least two PC's

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3

I have installed MVC3 RTM and when using VS2010 to create a blank project (or load an existing one) I get the following serious error:

`The project type is not supported by this installation.`

This is occurring on both of my development machines. I've tried all the usual suggestions like /resetskippkgs and /setup command line arguments to devenv.exe. These have no affect.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nevermind. Turns out you have to install "Visual Web Developer" which is a tick box option on the VS2010 installer.

Comment: You should flag this as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install MVC3 (http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc3).

Answer (score 1):

This problem can also occur if you install VS2010 *after* installing MVC3. Uninstall MVC3 (via add/remove programs) and reinstall to fix.